# "Enter filename"warning while running a tex code with MiKTeX

Tags: errors, pdftex, compilation-error

I am using latex code to generate my CV, and while using that it is showing following error.

[image]

I am getting this warning for particular this tex file. All other tex files are running smoothly.

PS: I am using ***WinEdt*** Editor.

Comment: Your MikTeX distribution apparently doesn't have (or find) the package `adjustbox`. This is completely unrelated to the editor.

Comment: Install the `adjustbox` package with MiKTeX console. It is not installed by default.

Comment: miktex definitely includes adjustbox so you should be able to install adjustbox via the miktex package manager

Comment: But I am using WinEdt.

Comment: @monalisa WinEdt is an **editor** is has nothing to do with your LaTeX installation (here your LaTeX installation is miktex). Winedt just handle editing the text and hands over all latex processing to miktex. (this is a very common confusing for new users).

Comment: BTW: normally miktex will ask to install a missing package, but for some editors the popup that asks whether it should install it gets blocked, so it might be an idea to run pdflatex on your doc from a dos promt/power shell, if miktex still does not ask to install it, check your miktex settings.

Comment: The reason is that last year when I tried it was working fine, but suddenly it is not working. Okay I will install the same.

Comment: One temporary alternative (to the cumbersome MikTeX installation) could be to save a copy of adjustbox.sty freely available from sources like http://www2.geog.ucl.ac.uk/~plewis/geogg122/Chapter3_Scientific_Numerical_Python/adjustbox.sty to the folder you have saved your CV in.  However, whether this'll work or not-- depends on the trustworthiness of the source.

Comment: In MiKTeX Console, choose "Settings" -> "Package Installation" -> "Ask me"

Comment: @monalisa While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: @samcarter I am  so sorry. It almost slipped my mind to accept the answers. Thank for reminding.

Comment: @monalisa Thank you very much for helping this site by accepting the answers that help you!